# 2D vector class variable for a genetic algorithm gives a bad_alloc error

Tags: c++, vector, genetic-algorithm, bad-alloc

I'm writing a genetic algorithm for which I'm creating a "crossover" operator as a class object that is passed the two parent "chromosomes"  Because the input and therefore the output chromosomes are variable lengths, my idea was two divide the input chromosomes and place in a sort of storage class variable, then resize the input chromosomes, and then finally refill the input chromosomes.  I'm getting a bad_alloc error, however.  If someone could spot my error I'd very much appreciate the help.

Thanks!  My class code is below.  Note that "plan_vector" is a 2d vector of int types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <eo>


class wetland_vector : public std::vector<int> {
public:
wetland_vector() : std::vector<int>(1, 0) {
}

};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, wetland_vector& q) {
for (unsigned int i = 0, n = 1; i < q.size(); ++i) {
    is >> q[i];
}
return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const wetland_vector& q) {
os << q[0];
for (unsigned int i = 1, n = 1; i < q.size(); ++i) {
    os << " " << q[i];
}
os << " ";
return os;
}

class wetland_vector_Init : public eoInit<wetland_vector> {
public:

void operator()(wetland_vector& q) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0, n = q.size(); i < n; ++i) {
        q[i] = rng.random(10);
    }
}
};


class plan_vector : public eoVector<double, wetland_vector> {
};


int read_plan_vector(plan_vector _plan_vector) {
for (unsigned i = 0; i < _plan_vector.size(); i++) {
    //Call function that reads Quad[1]
    //Call function that reads Quad[2]
    //etc
    return 0;
}
return 0;
};


class eoMutate : public eoMonOp<plan_vector> {
int subbasin_id_min;
int subbasin_id_max;
int wetland_id_min;
int wetland_id_max;

bool operator() (plan_vector& _plan_vector) {

    //decide which Quad to mutate
    int mutate_quad_ID = rng.random(_plan_vector.size());

    //decide which Gene in Quad to mutate 
    int mutate_gene_ID = rng.random(_plan_vector[mutate_quad_ID].size());

    //mutation procedure if first slot in the Quad is selected for mutation
    if (mutate_quad_ID = 0) {
        _plan_vector[mutate_quad_ID][mutate_gene_ID] = rng.random(subbasin_id_max);
    }

    //mutation procedure if second slot in the Quad is selected for mutation
    if (mutate_quad_ID = 1) {
        _plan_vector[mutate_quad_ID][mutate_gene_ID] = rng.random(subbasin_id_max);
    }

    //note: you'll need to add more for additional wetland characteristics

    return true;
   };

public:
void set_bounds(int, int, int, int);
};

void eoMutate::set_bounds(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

subbasin_id_min = a;
subbasin_id_max = b;
wetland_id_min = c;
wetland_id_max = d;

}

double evaluate(const plan_vector& _plan_vector) {

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < _plan_vector.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _plan_vector[i].size(); j++) {
        count += _plan_vector[i][j];
    }
}
return (count);
}

class eoQuadCross : public eoQuadOp<plan_vector> {
public:

std::string className() const {
    return "eoQuadCross";
}

plan_vector a1;
plan_vector a2;
plan_vector b1;
plan_vector b2;

bool operator() (plan_vector& a, plan_vector& b) {

    int cross_position_a = rng.random(a.size() - 1);
    int cross_position_b = rng.random(b.size() - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < cross_position_a; i++) {
        a1.push_back(a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = cross_position_a; i < a.size(); i++) {
        a2.push_back(a[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cross_position_b; i++) {
        b1.push_back(b[i]);
    }
    for (int i = cross_position_b; i < b.size(); i++) {
        b2.push_back(b[i]);
    }

    int size_a = b2.size() + a1.size();
    int size_b = a2.size() + b1.size();

    a.resize(size_a);
    b.resize(size_b);

    for (int i = 0; i < b2.size(); i++) {
        a.push_back(b2[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
        a.push_back(a1[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a2.size(); i++) {
        b.push_back(a2[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b1.size(); i++) {
        b.push_back(b1[i]);
    };

    //Return bool
    return true;
}

};



int main() {
unsigned int vec_size_min = 1;
unsigned int vec_size_max = 10;
unsigned int pop_size = 100;

//BEGIN COPY PARAMETRES
const unsigned int MAX_GEN = 100;
const unsigned int MIN_GEN = 5; 
const unsigned int STEADY_GEN = 50; 
const float P_CROSS = 0.8;
const float P_MUT = 0.5; 
const double EPSILON = 0.01;
double SIGMA = 0.3; 
const double uniformMutRate = 0.5;
const double detMutRate = 0.5; 
const double normalMutRate = 0.5;
//END COPY PARAMETERS

rng.reseed(1);

//Create population
wetland_vector_Init atom_init;
eoInitVariableLength<plan_vector> vec_init(vec_size_min, vec_size_max, atom_init);
eoPop<plan_vector> pop(pop_size, vec_init);

//Create variation operators
eoMutate mutate;
mutate.set_bounds(1, 453, 1, 4);
eoQuadCross crossover;
eoDetTournamentSelect<plan_vector> select(3);
eoSGATransform<plan_vector> transform(crossover, .5, mutate, .2);

//Create fitness function
eoEvalFuncPtr<plan_vector> eval(evaluate);

//Evaluate initial population and cout
apply<plan_vector > (eval, pop);
std::cout << pop << std::endl;

//Set GA for execution and execute
eoGenContinue<plan_vector> GenCount(5);
eoSGA<plan_vector> gga(select, crossover, .5, mutate, .1, eval, GenCount);
gga(pop);

//cout final population and end
std::cout << pop << std::endl;
std::cout << "The End" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting a bad_alloc error? Which allocation?

Comment: I guess I don't know.  It builds fine but when I run I get: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 108ms)

Answer (score 1):

```
a1.~vector();
a2.~vector();
b1.~vector();
b2.~vector();
```

You shall not destruct the vectors manually, otherwise the next time you try to access them (upon next call to the operator ()) you get undefined behavior.

Comment: I think that may have helped as the program ran a bit longer when I took those out.  Yet it still eventually gives a bad_alloc error.  Anything else that you spot?

Comment: @gcolumbus: perhaps you actually run out of memory? There is no enough context in your question to know this.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm coding on a virtual machine so perhaps I've given it too little.  I'll get back to you on this suggestion asap.

Comment: I have the machine 4gb of memory so I very much doubt that it runs out of memory given that it's a relative simple algorithm.  I've posted the entire code in my edit of the original post for your review.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `vector` destructor manually?? You should let C++ call that for you. If you want to clear the `vector` use `clear` member function

Comment: Yes, I took those out but the program still gives a bad_alloc error.  ...?

Comment: @gcolumbus You do not provide rest of your code, so we can't help you too much. But there is still some problems in your code: first reserve memory for `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, `b2` before push items into it to avoid to much memory reallocation. And you `resize` your vector and then push items to it, it will make vector twice the `a1.size() + b2.size9)` you should use `reserve` to reserve memory not `resize`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I've edited the above to include all of my code in case that helps.  I'll incorporate your suggestions asap.

Comment: You got it.  All I had to do was use reserve rather than resize.  Much appreciated!